# Erro de injeção de dependência

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando `Xunit` para realizar meus testes, estou tentando acessar minha `CampeonatosController`, consequentemente tenho que passar o valor mostrado na imagem abaixo como parâmetro, mas estou recebendo o erro abaixo.

Saberiam me auxiliar.

Minha classe de teste:

```
public class CampeonatoTest
{
    private const string IdReturnsOk = "2021";
    private const string IdNotFound = "XXXX";

    private readonly CampeonatosController _campeonato;

    private readonly ICompetitionService _competitionManager;

    public CampeonatoTest(
        CompetitionService competitionManager)
    {
        _competitionManager = competitionManager;

        _campeonato = new CampeonatosController(_competitionManager);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Campeonato_GetById_ValuesReturnsOkResponse()
    {
        var response = await _campeonato.Get(IdReturnsOk);

        var objectResponse = response as ObjectResult;

        Assert.Equal(200, objectResponse.StatusCode);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Campeonato_GetById_ReturnsNotFoundResponse()
    {
        var response = await _campeonato.Get(IdNotFound);

        var objectResponse = response as ObjectResult;

        Assert.Equal(404, objectResponse.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

E aqui está minha Controller:

```
public class CampeonatosController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICompetitionService _competitionManager;

    public CampeonatosController(
        CompetitionService competitionManager) 
    {
        _competitionManager = competitionManager;
    }

    // GET api/campeonatos/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage respToken = await _competitionManager.GetIdCompetitionAsync(id);

        string conteudo = respToken.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (respToken.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return Ok(conteudo);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note que o *controller* pede o tipo específico, não a interface. Isso está errado.

```
public CampeonatosController(CompetitionService competitionManager) 
{
    _competitionManager = competitionManager;
}
```

Deveria ser

```
public CampeonatosController(ICompetitionService competitionManager) 
{
    _competitionManager = competitionManager;
}
```

Comment: pior que esta implementada corretamente, estava lendo em alguns lugares que deveria fazer com `NMock`, mas não consegui implementar corretamente.

Comment: @Matheus É q tá errado no controller, né. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Fiz essa mudança mas continuo recebendo o erro `Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ICompetitionService competitionManager`

Comment: @Matheus Este erro não tem nada a ver com o da pergunta.

Comment: aparentemente não é possível utilizar injeção de dependência em aplicações de teste.

Comment: É possível sim, você deve estar falhando na implementação ou algo assim. De qualquer forma, sua pergunta original era sobre um problema e este problema é totalmente não relacionado. Se você precisa de ajuda para resolver o novo problema, abra uma nova pergunta. Senão, vamos acabar fugindo completamente do escopo desta publicação aqui.